# Within a function, Is there a way to determine if vim is in insert mode?

Tags: vimscript, insert-mode

Within a function, is there a way to determine if vim is in insert mode (or was in insert mode prior to calling the function)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Something* must have invoked your function. Setting the (new in Vim 8.0) asyncronous timers aside, this will be either

- a custom command, which cannot be invoked from insert mode, only command-line mode
- a mapping
- an `:autocmd` event

For the latter, you can split into two separate `:autocmd`s, and pass an `isInsertMode` flag into your function:

```
autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * call MyFunc()
```

turns into

```
autocmd CursorHold  * call MyFunc(0)
autocmd CursorHoldI * call MyFunc(1)
```

For mappings, you can pass a similar flag, or a character representing the mode (to also handle visual mode and so on):

```
:nnoremap <F2> :call MyFunc('n')<CR>
:vnoremap <F2> :<C-u>call MyFunc('v')<CR>
:inoremap <F2> <C-o>:call MyFunc('i')<CR>
```

That is the canonical approach, and should work for most use cases. If you have a really special need, please elaborate in your question.

Answer (score 7):

There is [`mode()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#mode()) function which can be used in some contexts (not thoroughly documented) with the following description:

```
mode([expr])    Return a string that indicates the current mode.
...
                  i       Insert
```

So, when it works, check for insert mode in your function can look like this:

```
if mode() == 'i'
    " in insert mode
endif
```

Comment: That only works under some special circumstances (as part of statusline evaluation, or map-expr, or a remote invocation). Its help even mentions this: _In most other places it always returns "c" or "n"._

Comment: "In most other places" is a rather vague term, unfortunately. For the `CursorMovedI` and `CursorMoved` events which I am particularly interested in, `mode()` seems to work. Within the `InsertEnter` event, however, `mode()` returns in fact `n`.

Answer (score 0):

**Jist of hinging behavior on the mode that you are in:**

The reason that determining what mode you're in is difficult is because you're trying to decide something in a place where that information is generally not kept.

So move upstream and put your hinge on mode in the `nnoremap`, `inoremap`, `vnoremap`, etc, like this:

```
nnoremap jj :call DecoupleDilithiumMatrix()
nnoremap jk :call EjectWarpCore()
```

Then you can put your mode-specific code in the functions.